# On a Web Page, All text box have Same Id and i want to write Same text in all box, by JavaScript from Chrome Console

Tags: javascript

**on a web page, All text box have same Id and i want to write same text in all box, by java script in Chrome Console, How it is possible, plz solve my issue**

{ document.getElementById('textbox').value = "Thanks"; }

this code is working But only for first textbox, not on all

```
{ document.getElementById('textbox').value = "Thanks"; }
```

There is "Thanks" is my word and "textbox" is id

Comment: `Id` should remain unique throughout the DOM. If you want multiple elements to have the same identifier, use `class` instead of `id`.

Comment: please explain in detail

Comment: `All text box have same Id`--> This is not correct. In any available DOM, the id for an element should not be repeated anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID's need to be unique in DOM.
Select the elements by tagname.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].value = "Thanks"
}
```

If you are using `jQuery` you can do it with this one-liner:

```
$('textarea').val("Thanks");
```

Comment: <div class="input-content style-scope paper-input-container">
      

      <div class="label-and-input-container style-scope paper-input-container" id="labelAndInputContainer">
        <label id="placeholder" aria-hidden="true" slot="label" class="style-scope ytcp-commentbox">
            Add a public reply...
          </label>

Comment: <iron-autogrow-textarea id="textarea" class="paper-input-input style-scope ytcp-commentbox" slot="input" maxlength="10000" required="true" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Add a public reply...">

    <div id="mirror" class="mirror-text style-scope iron-autogrow-textarea" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</div>

    
    <div class="textarea-container fit style-scope iron-autogrow-textarea">
      <textarea id="textarea" class="style-scope iron-autogrow-textarea" rows="1" autocomplete="off" required="" maxlength="10000"></textarea>

Comment: You can also select the elements by `tagname`. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks After a few try Your code is perfect work for me, Okey thank you

Answer (score 1):

you have to use a unique id for each element or same class.
with a class here is an example: $('.selectorname').val('value');

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic flaw in your code and in your understanding. You think that `All text box have same Id` because of this, `document.getElementById('textbox')` will return you all the textboxes. But that is not true. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id):-

> If the id value is not the empty string, it must be unique in a document.

According to this statement only one textbox can have that Id and `document.getElementById('textbox')` will return only the first match.

If you want multiple elements to be having the same identifier, please use [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) attribute.

```js
let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("inputClass");
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].value = "hello";
}
```

```html
<input class="inputClass" />
<input class="inputClass" />
```